# How to change side menu content for specific template

Tags: html, ionic-framework

I'm trying to create an app that has a different right side menu when viewing a certain view. There are examples online on how to replace certain buttons in for opening the sidemenu, but there are none of how to replace the content of the menu.
I've got the following code:

**menu.html (abstract view that all the other views inherit)**

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
  <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>
        <!-- Left side menu button -->
      <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
      <!-- Right side menu button, updates internetstatus on  click to determine whether or not to show music players-->
      <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-music-note" menu-toggle="right" ng-click="checkConn()">
        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <!-- Left side menu -->
  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
      <h1 class="title">Left</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/stages">
          Stages
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/info">
          Info
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/newsfeed">
          News feed
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/floorplan">
          Floorplan
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>

  <!-- Right side menu -->
  <ion-side-menu side="right">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
      <h1 class="title">Right</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item menu-close ng-show="internetconn" style="padding: 5px;" class="player">
          <iframe width="100%" height="60" src="https://www.mixcloud.com/widget/iframe/?embed_type=widget_standard&amp;embed_uuid=bbb2b97a-f82c-4732-a951-94fcf0a7dd72&amp;feed=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mixcloud.com%2FERMAHGERD_BERTMERN%2F0715-spieje-summer-mixtape%2F&amp;hide_cover=1&amp;hide_tracklist=1&amp;light=1&amp;mini=1&hide_artwork=1&amp;replace=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close ng-show="internetconn" style="padding: 5px;" class="player">
          <iframe width="100%" height="60" src="https://www.mixcloud.com/widget/iframe/?embed_type=widget_standard&amp;embed_uuid=8b9f98e7-dee8-4492-94b1-df72753057d9&amp;feed=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mixcloud.com%2FERMAHGERD_BERTMERN%2F0515-spieje-mixtape-mei-2015%2F&amp;hide_cover=1&amp;hide_tracklist=1&amp;light=1&amp;mini=1&hide_artwork=1&amp;replace=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close ng-show="internetconn" style="padding: 5px;" class="player">
          <audio style="width:100%" controls><source src="http://www.spieje.nl/downloads/mixtape/Spieje2015MixtapeApr.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close ng-hide="internetconn">
          Geen internet!
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

**Other view html (where menu must be different)**

```
<ion-view view-title="Floorplan">
    <!-- Override right button, change icon-->
    <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-map" menu-toggle="right">
        </button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
    <!-- Override right menu content -->
    <!-- Right side menu -->
    <ion-side-menu side="right">
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
            <h1 class="title">Right</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content>
            <ion-list>
                <ion-item>
                    <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-map"></button>
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item>
                    <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-paper-airplane"></button>
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item>
                    <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-transgender"></button>
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item>
                    <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-pizza"></button>
                </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-side-menu>
    <!-- Page content -->
    <ion-content>
        Image here
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

The button icon changes and works, but the result is that the right menu content stays the same and there is a weird list in the content view with the content I want to appear in the menu.

Is there a way to do this in the html like this, and if so, how. Or is my only option to use a boolean and use ng-show and ng-hide?

**EDIT**

I used a combination of *$rootScope*, *$ionicView.enter* and *$ionicView.leave* to keep track of when the view was selected. Then I used *ng-show* and *ng-hide* in the menu's.

The answer below is the answer to the question, but this didn't work for me as I had music players in the right menu and I wanted them to keep playing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use templates for each menu. The example below could help you:

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
      .state('tab', {
        url: '/tab',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
      })
    .state('tab.activity', {
      url: '/tab-activity',
      views: {
        'tab-activity': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-activity.html',
          controller: 'tabActivityCtrl'
        },
        'menu-right@tab': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-activity-menu.html'               
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tab.profile', {
      url: '/tab-profile',
      views: {
        'tab-profile': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-profile.html',
          controller: 'tabProfileCtrl'
        },
        'menu-right@tab': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-profile-menu.html'               
        }
      }
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/tab/tab-activity");

  })
  .controller('NavCtrl', function($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {
    $scope.showMenu = function() {
      $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();
    };
  })
 .controller('tabActivityCtrl', function($scope) {})
.controller('tabProfileCtrl', function($scope) {});
```

```html
<html ng-app="ionicApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

  <title>Tabs Example</title>

  <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

  <script id="templates/tabs.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-side-menus>

      <ion-side-menu-content ng-controller="NavCtrl">
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive nav-title-slide-ios7">
          <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon ion-arrow-left-c">
          </ion-nav-back-button>

          <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
            <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" ng-click="showMenu()">
          </button>
          </ion-nav-buttons>
          <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
            <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-music-note" ng-click="" menu-toggle="right">
          </button>
          </ion-nav-buttons>

          <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-positive">
            <!-- Activity Tab -->
            <ion-tab title="Activity" icon-off="ion-ios-pulse" icon-on="ion-ios-pulse-strong" href="#/tab/tab-activity">
              <ion-nav-view name="tab-activity"></ion-nav-view>
            </ion-tab>

            <!-- Profile Tab -->
            <ion-tab title="Profile" icon-off="ion-ios-people" icon-on="ion-ios-people" href="#/tab/tab-profile">
              <ion-nav-view name="tab-profile"></ion-nav-view>
            </ion-tab>
          </ion-tabs>
      </ion-side-menu-content>

      <!-- Left side menu (fixed) -->
      <ion-side-menu side="left">
        <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-assertive">
          <h1 class="title">Left Menu</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content has-header="true">
          <ul class="list">
            <li>
              <a class="item" menu-close nav-clear href="#/tab/home">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="item" menu-close href="#/tab/chat">Chat</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="item" menu-close href="#/tab/drink">Drink</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </ion-content>
        <ion-footer-bar class="bar bar-footer">
          <a class="button button-fullwidth" ui-sref="snd.policy" ng-click="toggleLeft()">Privacy Policy</a>
        </ion-footer-bar>
      </ion-side-menu>

      <!-- Right side menu (in templates different for each view) -->
      <ion-side-menu side="right">
        <div ui-view='menu-right' />
      </ion-side-menu>

    </ion-side-menus>


  </script>

  <script id="templates/tab-activity.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view title="tab-activity">
      <ion-content>
        <h3>tab-activity</h3>
        <p>Example of Ionic tabs. Navigate to each tab, and navigate to child views of each tab and notice how each tab has its own navigation history.</p>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>

  <script id="templates/tab-profile.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view title="tab-profile">
      <!-- Override right button, change icon-->
      <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-map" menu-toggle="right">
          </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
      <!-- Page content -->
      <ion-content>
        <h3>tab-profile</h3>
        <p>bla bla bla </p>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>


  <script id="templates/tab-activity-menu.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
      <h1 class="title">Activity Menu</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <ul class="list">
        <li>
          <a class="item" menu-close nav-clear href="#/tab/home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="item" menu-close href="#/tab/chat">Chat</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="item" menu-close href="#/tab/drink">Drink</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </ion-content>
  </script>

  <script id="templates/tab-profile-menu.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-assertive">
      <h1 class="title">Profile Menu</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <ul class="list">
        <li>
          <a class="item" menu-close nav-clear href="#/tab/home">Test</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="item" menu-close href="#/tab/chat">Check</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </ion-content>
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```